# WPF Localization: DynamicResource with StringFormat?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

I am doing localization in .NET 4 with a ResourceDictionary.  Does anyone have a solution for using a value with string format?

For instance, let's say I have a value with the key "SomeKey":

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <s:String x:Key="SomeKey">You ran {0} miles</s:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Using it in a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource SomeKey}" />
```

How would I combine, for example, an integer with the value of SomeKey as a format string?

Comment: Any strong reason to do localization in a ResourceDictionary instead of the (more common) resx resources?

Comment: So far I have a full xaml approach.  I'm also not completely sure if I can change the language at runtime with resx.  Currently, I am using external .xaml files that I can modify and load whenever I want to change languages quite easily (with the exception of the above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally came up with a solution that allows me to have format strings in my ResourceDictionary and be able to dynamically change the language at runtime.  I think it could be improved, but it works.

This class converts the resource key into its value from the ResourceDictionary:

```
public class Localization
{
    public static object GetResource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(ResourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetResource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ResourceProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Resource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Resource", typeof(object), typeof(Localization), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnResourceChanged));

    private static void OnResourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if ResourceReferenceExpression is already registered
        if (d.ReadLocalValue(ResourceProperty).GetType().Name == "ResourceReferenceExpression")
            return;

        var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe == null)
            return;

        //register ResourceReferenceExpression - what DynamicResourceExtension outputs in ProvideValue
        fe.SetResourceReference(ResourceProperty, e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

This class allows the value from the ResourceDictionary to be used as the format parameter in String.Format()

```
public class FormatStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[0] == null)
            return String.Empty;

        var format = (string)values[0];
        var args = values.Where((o, i) => { return i != 0; }).ToArray();

        return String.Format(format, args);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Example Usage 1**: In this example, I use the FormatStringConverter in the MultiBinding to convert its Binding collection into the desired output.  If, for instance, the value of "SomeKey" is "The object id is {0}" and the value of "Id" is "1" then the output will become "The object id is 1".

```
                <TextBlock ap:Localization.Resource="SomeKey">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource formatStringConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="(ap:Localization.Resource)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding Path="Id" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
```

**Example Usage 2**: In this example, I use a binding with a Converter to change the resource key to something more verbose to prevent key collisions.  If, for instance, I have the enum value Enum.Value (displayed by default as "Value"), I use the converter to attach its namespace to make a more unique key.  So the value becomes "My.Enums.Namespace.Enum.Value".  Then the Text property will resolve with whatever the value of "My.Enums.Namespace.Enum.Value" is in the ResourceDictionary.

```
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Enums}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEnum}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock ap:Localization.Resource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource enumToResourceKeyConverter}}"
                               Text="{Binding Path=ap:Localization.Resource), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

**Example Usage 3**: In this example, the key is a literal and is used only to find its corresponding value in the ResourceDictionary.  If, for instance, "SomeKey" has the value "SomeValue" then it will simply output "SomeValue".

```
                    <TextBlock ap:Localization.Resource="SomeKey"
                               Text="{Binding Path=ap:Localization.Resource), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind to a ViewModel.Value somehow, and then use a (nested) binding to a format string.

When you have only one value:

```
<TextBlock 
  Text="{Binding Path=DemoValue, StringFormat={StaticResource SomeKey}}" />
```

When you also have `{1}` etc then you need MultiBinding.

### Edit:

When you really want to change languages in a live Form then the sensible way is probably to do all formatting in the ViewModel. I rarely use StringFormat or MultiBinding in MVVM anyway.

Comment: You're right, DynamicResource won't work here. If you really want to change languages in an active Form then that is a problem. Most UI changers will just reload the Form(s) though. It's a little expensive to have dynamic resources throughout for just that feature.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to realize that.  I could add some sort of translation service at my viewmodel layer that would handle it.  I'm still learning MVVM pattern, and I found it easiest so far to handle all of the translation in the View.

Comment: Agreed. A lot easier to unit test and handle more complex formatting / multi-bind by doing more in the VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to bind and format a Miles property to a 'TextBlock' you can do as follows:

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Miles, StringFormat={StaticResource SomeKey}}"/>`

Comment: It must be a DynamicResource because it is being loaded from a ResourceDictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergeDictionaries.

Comment: Well, Static/Dynamic makes little difference here. And MergedDictionaries don't automatically require Dynamic.

Comment: DynamicResource can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependenyObject.  In my case, DynamicResource is a must because I wish to load the resource at runtime.