# How to set a DynamicResource as PriorityBinding?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a multilanguage application which contains two dictionary `en.xaml` and `it.xaml`, suppose that I have the following situation:

I need to display a default text in a `TextBlock` such as: `Contact saved 0 in memory` using a DynamicResource key that contains the text above.

Unfortunately xaml doesn't allow to use `DynamicResource` in a `StringFormat` or as `FallbackValue` so I used this code:

```
<TextBlock Tag="{DynamicResource defaultContactStr}">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <PriorityBinding>
     <Binding Path="ContactSaved" />
     <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
   </PriorityBinding>
 </TextBlock.Text>
```

this will display only `0` which is the default value of the proeprty `ContactSaved`, but I need to display: `Contact saved 0 in memory`, or if the value change: `Contact saved 5 in memory` etc...

how can I manage this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925145/wpf-localization-dynamicresource-with-stringformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `StringFormat` works only if the format (the translation in your case) is known at compile-time:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="ContactSaved" StringFormat="{}Contact saved {0} in memory" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Othwerwise you may handle this using a converter and a `MultiBinding`:

```
public class CustomConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string resource = values[0] as string;
        string contactSaved = values[1].ToString();

        return string.Format(resource, contactSaved);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Tag="{DynamicResource defaultContactStr}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:CustomConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
            <Binding Path="ContactSaved" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

**en.xaml:**

```
<system:String x:Key="defaultContactStr">Contact saved {0} in memory</system:String>
```

Remember that XAML is nothing but a *markup* language.